# Selenium webdriver store webelement in webelement list

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to store webelement in webelement list? I have created list for webelement and passing webelement obj in add method, but system display null exception. 
Java Code: `List<WebElement> element=null;` and in for loop i am passing webelement obj in add method like: `WebElement we = driver...("test"); element.add(0,we);`

Why I am getting null pointer exception (`java.lang.NullPointerException`)?

I would appreciate your inputs.

```
 public void test(){
 List<WebElement> element = null;

    int rows=1;
    for(int i=1; i<=rows;i++){
        text=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='testid']/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td/p")).getText();
        if(!text.equals("")){
            for(int j=1;j<=rows;j++){
                if(isElementPresent(driver, By.xpath("//*[@id='testid']/table/tbody/tr["+(j+1)+"]/td[6]/a"))){
                    WebElement we =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='testid']/table/tbody/tr["+(j+1)+"]/td[6]/a"));
                    element.add(we);
                    rows++;
                }
            }
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    for(WebElement we:element){
        we.click();
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add the code snippet please ?

Comment: I have added code snippet

Comment: The approach of @Nahuel below is correct. Please try that and let us know in case there are further concerns.. :)

Comment: @Subh, just want to know when we write code like List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.id("test")). System does not give any null pointer exception. Why?

Comment: Because return type of **findElements() method** is **List<WebElement>**. This link has the method's description: [https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By)](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By)).. Hope you get it.. :)

Comment: It won't give you nullpointer exception, since findElements return an empty list if no element is found. Exception is thrown only in case of findElement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You setted element to null and then tried to add something to it. You cannot add anything to it as it IS null!

Instead, try this:

```
List<WebElement> element=new ArrayList<WebElement>();
...
```

As you can see, I initialized the object before using it, so it no longer should be null.

Comment: and you initialized it with an `Interface` at RHS. use a concrete class like `new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Oops, I'm not familiar with java, I thought it was just the same as C#. Updated the answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your following line :

```
 WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='testid']/table/tbody/tr["+(j+1)+"]/td[6]/a"));
```

With following :

```
 java.util.List<WebElement> element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='testid']/table/tbody/tr["+(j+1)+"]/td[6]/a"));
```

Also you can get list size using :  System.out.println(we.size());
Let me know if any query.

Comment: Hey, I cannot use this, as I want to store the new found element in element list as second line which you have given will always create new list.

Comment: You should put that line out of loop. It will store list in element and then you can call it within loop if needed.

Answer (score 0):

List albums = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("._3rte"))

Worked for me.

The selector is of course up to you. The first part is the important bit